# How to trigger event from directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `directive` with code

```
seriesClick: function (e) {
                //console.log(e.category);
                // use scope.$emit to pass it to controller
                scope.$emit('feederValue', e.category);
            },
```

In my `controller` I am using

```
        $scope.$on('feederValue', function (evt, value) {
            console.log(value);
            $scope.feederFitBoundValue = value;
            $scope.getFitBoundForFeederID($scope.feederFitBoundValue);
        });
```

I want to define this function in my different directive 
And I want to use it

My code

```
function getFitBoundForFeederID(feederFitBoundValue){
    alert(feederFitBoundValue);
}
```

I am getting error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

My project is in `Angular` framework I want to use logic of `$emit` and `$on`

Please suggest if any optimus solution. I just want to pass value from One directive to different directive. same time I want to pass some value from one directive to another. I want to do event triggering.

Answer (score 0):

An easy fix would be to emit the event on the `$rootScope` and watching this event on the `$rootScope` as well, but i'm not sure it's the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To pass value from one directive to another you can use factory to create your service which holds the shared data.

```
app.factory("sharedDataService", function() {
            return {
                yourData: "anything"
            };
        });
```